# C++ Calling a vector inside a function through a function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, function-pointers

In a program I'm working on, I've declared a vector in main. I have two functions that use the vector: an int function, and a standard void 'print' function. I'm attempting to use a function pointer (pointing to the int function) in the void function, but I get the error that the vector has not been declared, even though it's in main. I've tried declaring the vector outside of main, and the function worked fine, but I'm hesitant on keeping it outside of main. I was wondering if there was some way to use the vector in the void function when it was declared in main. Here's some example code for what I'm asking:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int returnSquare(vector<int>& numbers);
void print(int (*squarePtr)(vector<int>&));
int (*squarePtr)(vector<int>&);

int main()
{
   vector<int> v(1);
   squarePtr = &returnSquare;

   for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
   {
       v.at(i) = i * 25;
       cout << v.at(i) << " ";
   }

   print(squarePtr);

   return 0;
}

int returnSquare(vector<int>& numbers)
{
     int product = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
     {
        product = numbers.at(i) * numbers.at(i);
     }
     return product;
}

void print(int (*squarePtr)(vector<int>&))
{
    int answer = (*squarePtr)(v);
    cout << answer << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `print` you have just one parameter. To call your squaring function you need to pass the vector to square to it, something like:

```
void print(int (*squarePtr)(vector<int>&), vector<int> &v)
{
    int answer = (*squarePtr)(v);
    cout << answer << endl;
}
```

Without that the variable `v` is not visible inside the function. The call should look like:

```
    print(squarePtr, v);
```

Less important. You use the `squarePtr` name in your global definitions twice. This does not bring clarity to your code. You better write:

```
void print(int (*workerFuncPtr)(vector<int>&));
int (*squarePtr)(vector<int>&);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void print (int (*squarePtr)(vector<int>&))
```

This parameter only accepts a pointer to your square function, that's it. It doesn't hold a pointer or a reference to your `v` variable. Your print function has no idea what `v` is, unless you pass `v` as an argument, or make `v` a global variable (which is what you did moving it out of main).

Do this:

```
// Modify your print definition to accept a reference to your vector `v`
void print(int (*squarePtr)(vector<int>&), vector<int>& v);

// Add `v` as the second argument to your print call
print(squarePtr, v);

// Modify the definition of your print function to accept a reference to your vector `v`
void print(int (*squarePtr)(vector<int>&), vector<int>& v)
{
  ...
}
```